# RC Schmitt Trigger Debouncing - Cap discharged but there is a voltage across it still

Tags: switches, debounce

[image]

As you can see in the image, I'm running the example given in [here](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm) where I would debounce the limit switch. I'm running the [SN7414](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7414.pdf) with the given resistors in the diagram. The problem here is that with the calculated resistors, I'm still getting a 0.818V across the capacitor, and from the datasheet, the SN7414 will only switch to logic high when the voltage is at the minimum 0.6V.

The guide talked about input leakage current (Ii), which turns out to be 1mA for the SN7414. I measured the current going towards the SN7414 when the limit switch was closed turns out to be 130uA which causes a theoretical biased voltage of 1.066V but the measured voltage is 0.829V. This prevents the SN7414 from reaching it's negative going threshold... which prevents the SN7414 from triggering a rising edge.

In the guide, they used a [74AHCT14](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AHC_AHCT14.pdf) where the Ii = 1uA... this is substantially smaller than in the SN7414.

1. Am I looking at the right place as to why there is a potential across the cap after the switch is closed?
2. How do I compensate for this? I can lower the value in R2 by using a 10uF cap.

   Note: ignore the "0.733V when switch is closed" in the diagram, that was when R2 = 4.7kohms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen the SN7414. If you look at the schematic in the data sheet page 3, you will see that internally there is a 6K ohm resistor tied high to Vcc and then through a diode to the input pin A of the 7414. So your capacitor is being charged up by the input from the 7414.

Either use the 74AHCT14 (or equivelant) or reduce your resistors to values low enough that your resistors can soak up the (almost) 0.8 mA (edit, I originally said 8mA incorrectly) from the 7414. Meaning your R2 needs to be a lot smaller.

Comment: Does the datasheet say 8 mA or did you calculate that? If so, how? Because I got about 0.8 mA.

Comment: @user2066639 . Calculated : \$ (5v-0.6v)/6000 \$ - Gives about 7.3mA .  But with your 8.2K resistor, the current will be less. Also, it might be that your 7414 is the LS (Low power version, which would be even less current). Look at the lower schematic in data sheet where 20K resistor is used.

Comment: @user2066639 correcting myself now. I can't even do arithmetic today. The equation in my previous calculates to 0.73 mA.  Sorry about that

Comment: You're correct, I was looking at the wrong part, LS14 is the one. When you say 'resistors can soak up 0.8mA', do you mean that the resistance is low enough that it does not create a high potential? V = IR, since we want V to be below VT-, we would decrease R in order to achieve that? Since I is constant. Just not familiar with the terminology. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, and my apology for speaking in slang.